# How to check whether the user's data (username & email address) exist in database or not by using SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have made a relational model for my application. Now I want to write the queries for different tasks given in information flow diagram. I am confused here that how to check that the user entered name and password exists in database?

Comment: What host language are you using? Php? Java? dot net? It matters because each of them has its own way of validating password hashes.

Comment: I have to write the query in SQL.

Comment: I am using php as my host language.

Comment: Need help immediately....Thankyou

Comment: There are dozens of examples and tutorials on using php and MySQL to create user-validation code.  A search for "php mysql login example code" might help you find some of them.

Comment: You may have a `user` table then you can query it like `select count(*) from user where userName = :userName And password= :password`, If it returns `NULL` or `0` he is not exist ;).